# html5 mobile app auto login

Tags: php, jquery, html

I've developed a mobile app using HTML5, jQuery and PHP. As of now, every time a user opens a app, he needs to enter username and password to login.

I would now like to provide auto login facility, which will directly take user to app without entering credentials.

What is to be done so that I can accomplish this thing in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing is to use localStorage so when the app loads, checks for that and send it to the serves. This is good if you have a web app that does not reload every time. While if you have an app that everytime you click it reloads the page, maybe is easier using a cookie, so the server can parse it. And log you in

Comment: but from security point of view, is it good to store Username and Password in local storage?

Comment: to access it, you have to have access to the physical hardware, but I would not store username and password, I would store an hash. with that hash you can know which user it is from the server side.